# How do to add a . to the last part of a path in applescript?

Tags: macos, applescript

I am renaming the name of a file in order to basically hide it from other users of my computer cause im pretty private about stuff. Im doing this in applescript and have a list of file names I want to change. I have heard of delimiters but dont know how to use it. How might i change this in Applescript -

`/Users/username/Desktop/file.txt`

into

`/Users/username/Desktop/.file.txt`

Comment: If you want to protect really your private stuff, disabling permissions for others to **read/write** your file and locking it with **password** and Finder makes more sense. Because everybody can unhide the hidden files. Also, System Events (and bunch of other tools) can list hidden files of a folder even without  unhiding files in the Finder.

Answer (score 0):

Delimiters are to aid in processing text which isn't really an issue in your situation.

To rename a single file using applescript, first work with it as an alias, then set its name to something new.

```
set fName to POSIX file "/Users/username/Desktop/file.txt"
set aName to fName as alias
tell application "Finder" to set name of aName to ".file.txt"
```

To rename a list of files from a text document (assuming one file per line), read the document, make a list of its lines, then cycle through the list. Inside the loop, the posix reference is coerced into an alias which enables us to work with the file's name property.

```
use scripting additions

-- specify file containing list of files to rename
set pfListing to POSIX path of (path to desktop as text) & "lista.txt"
--> "/Users/username/Desktop/lista.txt"

-- Contains one entry per line, like this:
-- /Users/username/Desktop/file1.txt
-- /Users/username/Desktop/file2.txt

-- read contents into list of files
set fList to paragraphs of (get read pfListing)
--> {"/Users/username/Desktop/file1.txt", "/Users/username/Desktop/file2.txt"}

tell application "Finder"
    repeat with fp in fList -- each file path
        tell me to set afp to POSIX file (contents of fp) as alias
        set name of afp to "." & name of afp
    end repeat
end tell
--> /Users/username/Desktop/.file1.txt
--> /Users/username/Desktop/.file2.txt
```

If you have a list of the renamed files, and wish to revert to their original names, replace the 'set name…' line with these:

```
    set chgName to name of afp
    set origName to text 2 thru -1 of chgName
    set name of afp to origName
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response it was really helpful. However, the only problem I have is that i don't know the exact name of .file.txt as it is in a list. I just want to know how to change the last part of a file paths name. Thanks!